# SharePoint 2013 KeywordQuery Search SPField

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, keywordquery

The SharePoint search service works on documents content and it Metadata (properties), I need to retrieve the field name and it content (SPField) which the search are matched on it.

What field should I add to the SelectProperties object ? or where I can find these information.

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);

keywordQuery.QueryText = queryText;
keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
var selecProperties = keywordQuery.SelectProperties;
selecProperties.Add("UniqueId");
selecProperties.Add("FileLeafRef");
selecProperties.Add("ListId");
selecProperties.Add("WebId");
selecProperties.Add("Created");
selecProperties.Add("CheckoutUserOWSUSER");

SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults).FirstOrDefault();
DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the `KeywordQuery` object in the property `HitHighlightedProperties` all needed is to add crawled properties (managed properties) to `SelectProperties` and `HitHighlightedProperties`, then in the field you will find xml contains details about the found keyword in all available fields.